# Where can I find what LCG's exist?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-lcg

I know of four Living Card Games:

- Warhammer
- Call of Cthulhu
- game of Thrones
- Lord of the rings

Is there somewhere that maintains a canonical list of all LCG's?

Comment: Welcome to the site. At Boardgames.SE, we prefer questions that do not encourage lists. These questions tend to have multiple answers, and are not a good fit the Q&A voting system. Your question is "probably" not overly broad, and might just have 1 definitive answer, because of a technicality due to the LCG trademark that you might not have been aware of. Although, I might be wrong and you are really only asking about the LCG **model**. Some more detail in your question might help for us to better answer it, or narrow it's scope.

Comment: I have reworded the question so that it does not trip our list "filter" IMHO.

Comment: Warhammer is technically called Warharmmer: Invasion. It is no longer being added to by FFG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **Living Card Game** is a trademark of Fantasy Flight Games, you should just be able to check their [product page](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_colecciones.asp?eidc=3) and find out.

You are missing:

> Android: Netrunner the Card Game
>
> Star Wars: The Card Game

If you are asking if there are any expandable card games, where there isn't any randomness in the cards you get with each expansion (I.E. This is unlike Magic: the Gathering's **Trading/Collectible Card** game model, with booster packs that are **random** so you have no idea what you are getting), then it would be difficult to track. There have been other games using the LCG model, but cannot use the term for Trademark infringement reasons.

- [Summoner Wars](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/games/summoner-wars) by Plaid Hat Games
- [Killer Bunnies](http://killerbunnies.com/) by Playroom Entertainment

Comment: Ok awesome. I was asking about the trademark of FFG

Comment: You forgot the new game Warhammer 40,000: Conquest.